# child_process.exec() stdout is empty string when command contains spaces

Tags: node.js

I have put the below code in a Javascript file and ran it using node.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

child = exec("git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate), %(authorname)' --sort=committerdate --merged develop",

    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('typeof stdout: ' + typeof stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

All I get is an empty string as stdout. There are no errors.

```
stdout: 
stderr:
```

However, if I remove the space after comma in "%(committerdate), %(authorname)", I get the expected output. The below code works:-

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

child = exec("git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate),%(authorname)' --sort=committerdate --merged develop",
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
});
```

Why do I not  get any output when there is a space after comma?

When I run the command directly on in PowerShell or git-bash, I get the same output with and without the space.

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate), %(authorname)' --sort=committerdate --merged develop
```

I spent quite some time to get the command working and it seemed to be that a space would cause an issue, especially when the command works fine when run directly.

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Node 16.7.0

Comment: Different commands can be interpreted differently on different operating systems, different versions of node, different underlying shells, varying treatment of quotes, etc. The last person who tried to pinpoint the all of differences across all systems went insane and now lives in a hospital. It is rumored that this person keeps repeating the phrase _"we must escape, we must escape"_. Maybe give that a shot? Try a backslash or a backtick or any of the other escape characters in front of the space.

Comment: I spent an hour _escape_ ing multiple characters of the command. The `git` command I've put in the question is a strip down version of the beast I'm dealing with. I could not _escape_ out of my problem. I was lucky to have figured out the space.

Comment: Some things I've seen suggest double slashes (`foo\\ bar`) or even triple (`foo\\\ bar`). Also, I think node might use `cmd.exe` under the hood, so make sure it works there, or maybe figure out how to invoke powershell.exe with the arguments you want.

Comment: cmd.exe is indeed the culprit. Running with powershell.exe solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth putting into an answer to give people ideas on how to troubleshoot.

Let's look at the command first:

```js
exec("git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate), %(authorname)' --sort=committerdate --merged develop", ...);
```

If we wanted to look at the underbelly of the `exec` function, we would probably find a more sophisticated version of `inputString.split(" ")` so that node can distinguish the executable from the positional arguments/flags. So a good place to start is to try and escape the space in various ways to see if that works.

Next you need to understand how node executes the command. On different operating systems, the node `child_process` library is just a proxy to an underlying shell. So you need to make sure your command works in the target shell (which is likely not your favorite shell or the one you use on a day-to-day basis). For Windows, node likely uses `cmd.exe` under the hood.

Lastly, the `child_process` library also allows you to [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) a process which is a little more deliberate in specifying the executable and positional arguments/flags. I recommend using this method for most child_process operations:

```js
spawn(<executable>, [...<args>]);
```

This way you are telling node exactly what binary to use while clearly identifying every positional argument. For example, the following will fail:

```js
spawn('git', ['checkout -b my-new-branch']);
```

The reason this fails is because node treats the string `'checkout -b my-new-branch'` as a single argument to the git command... which is not correct. Instead, you want to clearly define each positional argument separately:

```js
spawn('git', ['checkout', '-b', 'my-new-branch']);
```

This is particularly useful if one of your arguments contains spaces or other special shell characters:

```js
spawn('git', ['checkout', '--format=\'%(committerdate), %(authorname)\'', '--sort=committerdate', '--merged develop']);
```

#### Changing the underlying shell

For any of the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) creation methods, you can pass an option for which shell to use. Be careful using this option because you can destroy the ability for your code to run on multiple operating systems. Make sure to read about [shell requirements](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#shell-requirements) and the [default windows shell](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#default-windows-shell):

```js
exec("...", { shell: "powershell.exe" });
spawn("...", [...], { shell: "powershell.exe" });
```

Comment: >For Windows, node likely uses cmd.exe under the hood
The default shell on Windows is cmd.exe. 
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#default-windows-shell

Comment: It is worth updating the answer with with shell option which actually solved the problem.

`exec("git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate), %09%(authorname), %09%(refname:short)' --sort=committerdate --merged develop", {'shell':'powershell.exe'}, ....`

or in case of spawn

`const child = spawn("git", ['for-each-ref', '--format=\'%(committerdate), %(authorname), %(refname:short)\'', '--sort=committerdate', '--merged', 'develop'], { shell: 'powershell.exe' });`

Comment: I updated the answer - though you should watch out for keeping your script cross-platform friendly, as any node project should be. It's just good practice, even if you know it's only going to run on windows.